# Special 2 row 4 column Menu - responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

I tried to build a website with a Special landingpage. Design specific i`d like to build it like that.
[image]

To do this I wrote the following code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header_section">
    </div>
    <div id="main_section">
        <div id="menu_section">
            <div class="first_row">
                <div class="row_element_4 first_element_row"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="second_row">
                <div class="row_element_4 first_element_row"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
                <div class="row_element_4"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_section">

    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
/* Main Section */
#main_section
{
background: url("../images/background/bg_person.jpg");
width: 100%;
height: 70%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu_section
{
    margin: 0 auto;
width: 95%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 95%;
    background: blue;
}
.first_row
{
   background: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 49%;
}
.second_row
{
   background: orange;
   width: 100%;
   height: 49%;
   margin-top: 1%;
}
.row_element_4
{
   height: 100%;
   width: 24%;
   background: aqua;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 1%;
}
.first_element_row
{
   margin-left: 0.5%;
}
```

My Problem is the responsive Design when I resize the window as shown in the Image below:
[image]

My row elements don't look like a square anymore. 
How can I fix this Problem with my design staying responsive?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If you wants `height` always equal to `width` then you will need to remove hard coded `height` properties from your code.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54zLpdr1/). May be it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` 
Check it here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find useful `vw` and `vh` units. Define width and height are equal 95vw and you'll get ideal square

```
#menu_section
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95vw;
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 95vw;
    background: blue;
}
```

BTW, here's a doubled margin-top definition